# C++ How to call constructor and store in object in header file?

Tags: c++

Sorry if the question is unclear.
I have an object of a class declared in my header file because I need that object later, but I need to call that constructor from the cpp file.
But when I for example write `Class class(something_in_constructor);`

This is not the same object as I declared in the header file. Does anyone know how to call the constructor of that class and actually "store" it in the object created in the header file?

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Example of what I am trying to do(this won't compile, I know but just for example):

Test.h:

```
class Test {
private:
    Class class;
    void callConstructor();
};
```

Test.cpp:

```
void Test::callConstructor() {
    Class class(something); //THIS WORKS I KNOW BUT I NEED THE OBJECT I CREATED IN TEST.H FOR LATER USE BUT I CAN NOT CALL CONSTRUCTOR IN HEADER FILE
    class = class(something); //THIS DOES NOT WORK BUT MAYBE IT IS CLEARER NOW WHAT I NEED TO DO

}
```

Comment: If you want to access an object everywhere, you might want to look into a singleton, or static class. Though global objects are generally considered bad for maintainability.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] of what you have in your question.

Comment: "Code says more than a thousand pictures", or something to that effect.

Comment: Show us some code of the exact problem. The community can't guess _roughly_ what you want to achieve, instead they're gonna close your question until it's corrected. The higher purpose of these Q&A are for _other_ people to be able to relate to your question and find relevant answers.

Comment: I don't have code on this yet. This is just a question on how to do this. I guess some people did not even read my question, but just disliked because they did not saw any code...

Comment: I edited my question with example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you're trying to do is to **delay** the construction of the member `class` until the function `callConstructor` is called?

In that case, what happens is that all class members are initilized when the class `Test` itself is constructed, and for those members that no arguments are supplied for their constructors, they will be [*default initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

So at the point where the function `callConstructor` is called, `class` is already constructed using default initialization.

If you want to supply arguments to it's constructor, then you have to supply them upon the construction of the parent class `Test`.

Classes can't be initialized with uninitialized class members using automatic storage duration, this would be an error.

Alternatively you can use dynamic allocation through a smart pointer as [**`std::unique_ptr`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), *e.g.*,

```
class Test {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Class> class;
    void callConstructor();
};

void Test::callConstructor() {
    class = std::make_unique<Class>(ARG1, ARG2);
}
```

However, this is not the same, as the creation of the object will not take place until `callConstructor` is called (the smart pointer's internal reference will be initialized to `nullptr` upon construction). This means that accessing `class` before calling function `callConstructor` will result in a `nullptr`.

Comment: error C2039: 'unique_ptr': is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 `std::unique_ptr` is part of the C++11 standard. You need at least VS 2010 to be able to use it (or GCC 4.4).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Maybe you forgot to include header `<memory>` then?